# Function should return a record or a pointer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Let's say I have a "heavy" record, for example containing multiples dynamic arrays of values. I declare it this way:

```
PMyHugeRecord^ = TMyHugeRecord;
TMyHugeRecord = record
  AFirstArray: TSingleDynArray;
  // many many others
  ...  
  ALastArray: TSingleDynArray;
end;
```

While processing takes place in a function, should the result of the function be typed as a pointer, or can it return a record variable?

```
function MyFunctionWhichCalculates: TMyHugeRecord;
// or
function MyFunctionWhichCalculates: PMyHugeRecord;
```

I mean in terms of performance, especially to avoid a stack overflow. In other words, does a function return a result by reference or by value?

Comment: Just to point out the record you've described might not be as "heavy" as you think. Dynamic Arrays are allocated on the heap and reference counted. Your record structure holds 'light' references to the arrays. Similar for the default strings (long strings). However, if you have fixed size arrays, then your structure may be large. You can use `SizeOf(...)` to determine the size of your array.

Comment: You're right and my example wasn't the best one. Indeed my records can be a mix of various data types, including fixed size arrays and even other records. I maybe exagerated the "huge" term, but I'm always interested in optimizing my code.

Comment: The only reliable way to optimise your code is to use combination of benchmarking and profiling and test the difference of specific changes. Intuition can often be misleading. I cannot stress enough the benefit of having the majority of your code easily maintainable so that it's easier to ***safely*** tweak your code in the places where you need to fine-tune performance.

Comment: You're asking a performance question. What results did you see when you *measured* the performance? There's your answer.

Comment: @RobKennedy I did not. Yet. But if a widely known technique is a must-do practise I prefer to use it, regardless of the pure performance gain achieved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can return a record. It doesn't matter if it is "heavy" or not, as in reality, it will be passed in as reference parameter, in other words *as if* you had declared:

```
procedure MyFunctionWhichCalculates(var Result: TMyHugeRecord);
```

Do not return a pointer, even if you allocated a record with `New()`, because that leaves the user with the burden of `Dispose()`-ing the record through the pointer. This is no problem (but still a burden) in the same app, it is a problem across module borders, because of different memory managers. All in all, it is not recommended.

Comment: *This is no problem in the same app*. It's a problem even in the same app because it's much harder to manually keep track of the lifetime than it is to let the compiler do so.

Comment: I meant it is not a problem with different memory managers. The burden on the user is more or less the same.

Comment: You can't pass this record across modules with different memory managers anyway. It's a managed type. So that part of your answer is a somewhat moot anyway. All that aside, you are quite right, a pointer is a really poor idea here.

Comment: You can, if you provide a function in your module that disposes of the record, which then uses the same memory manager as the one used to allocate it. That is what some APIs do, but I would simply not recommend it.

Comment: Nope. Because of the managed types. When that record gets finalised, the dyn array members of the record will be finalised. Using the wrong memory manager.

Comment: If there is a function that disposes the record, they get finalized. But I agree that that is only safe with a shared memory manager, because the user might change the dynarrays in the app. Generally, it is not a good idea to pass managed types (or any Delphi-specific type) across module borders, indeed

Comment: OK, if the exported deallocator does finalization too then that would be fine, but you'd need to export one such function for every type! Gah! Working on the dynarrays is indeed another problem

Comment: That is why I would not recommend it. <g>

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RudyVelthuis that is exactly information that I was looking for but could not find in doc. By the way I was allocating and freeing the pointer out of the function itself. But I won't anymore!

Comment: The information is in the documentation. In the program control topic. You can't have looked very hard. The language docs are not very long. You can skim read them in no time so that you know what there is there.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment @DavidHeffernan, you're always so kind with people asking for help. Be sure that I've read this damn doc at least one thousand times since D5, by the way I think I've never seen a worst document than D2007's one. So yes, I have looked hard, as I always do before asking, and yes the doc is very long. Not my pleasure to ask something here to get this kind of remarks.

Comment: @paradise: The Delphi (or Object Pascal) Language Guide is part of the online help of every version of Delphi, and it explains it all. IMO, everyone should read it once every two years.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis But I do, for many years. More and more I use docwiki.embarcadero.com now. But it does not prevent that sometimes I can not find information that I'm looking for. In this particular case, to know what returns a function I looked in... guess what: "Procedures and Functions" chapter. Didn't think that it could be located in "Program Control" chapter. Maybe should I memorize the whole TOC, but if everyone did it there wouldn't be SO anymore :)

Comment: FWIW, I wrote an article on writing DLLs: [DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html). That discusses such issues and some others.