# Is it possible to return an internal record by reference so it can be further modified?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a record that contains an array of other records.

I would like the function that adds elements to that internal array to return the new record, so it can be further modified instead of needing dozens of parameters on the Add function itself. And I thought that [all records are always returned by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978225/function-should-return-a-record-or-a-pointer).

```
type
  TDatasetInfo = record
    Childs: array of TDatasetInfo;
    Name: string;
    PrimaryKey: TStringDynArray;
    MasterKey: TStringDynArray;
    RelationFields: TStringDynArray;
    SaveChanges: Boolean;
    CascadeDeletes: Boolean;
    ManualOpening: Boolean;
    function AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray; PrimaryKey: TStringDynArray = []; SaveChanges: boolean = True; ManualOpening: boolean = False; CascadeDeletes: boolean = True): TDatasetInfo;
    procedure Open(Key: Variant; Container: TComponent);
    function ChildCount: integer;
    class operator Initialize (out Dest: TDatasetInfo);
  end;

function TDatasetInfo.AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray; PrimaryKey: TStringDynArray = []; SaveChanges: boolean = True; ManualOpening: boolean = False; CascadeDeletes: boolean = True): TDatasetInfo;
var Child: TDatasetInfo;
begin
  if Length(PrimaryKey) = 0 then
    PrimaryKey := GetPrimaryKey(Dataset);   

  Child.name := Dataset.Name;
  Child.Childs := [];
  Child.SaveChanges := SaveChanges;
  Child.ManualOpening := ManualOpening;
  Child.CascadeDeletes := CascadeDeletes;
  Child.RelationFields := RelationFields
  Child.PrimaryKey := PrimaryKey

  Self.Childs := Self.Childs + [Child];
  Result := Self.Childs[Self.ChildCount - 1];
end;
```

But when I try to further configure a new child, I get an error that left side cannot be modified.

```
procedure TdmProduct.SetupDatasetInfo(var ADatasetInfo: TDatasetInfo);
begin
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductLanguage, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductInventoryLevel, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qVendorProduct, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductWarning, ['product']);
  with ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductRelatedStock, ['product']) do
    CascadeDeletes := False;  // <--- Compilation error: Left side cannot be modified
end;
```

The best I've been able to do is to return a pointer to the new internal record.

```
type
  PTDatasetInfo = ^TDatasetInfo;

  TDatasetInfo = record
    Childs: array of TDatasetInfo;
    ...
    ...
    function AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray): PTDatasetInfo;
  end

function TDatasetInfo.AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray: PTDatasetInfo;
begin
  ...
  ...
  Result := @Self.Childs[Self.ChildCount - 1];
end;
```

But I can't still directly change the returned record, I get an 'Record, object or class type required'. I need to assign that result to a variable first to be able to change it.

```
procedure TdmProduct.SetupDatasetInfo(var ADatasetInfo: TDatasetInfo);
begin
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductLanguage, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductInventoryLevel, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qVendorProduct, ['product']);
  ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductWarning, ['product']);

  var Child := ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductRelatedStock, ['product']);
  Child.CascadeDeletes := False; 
end;
```

Is there a way to declare the returning record so it can be changed directly ?. Like this:

```
  with ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductRelatedStock, ['product']) do
    CascadeDeletes := False;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally gone with returning a Pointer to the new internal record.

```
type
  PointerToDatasetInfo = ^TDatasetInfo;

  TDatasetInfo = record
    Childs: array of TDatasetInfo;
    ...
    ...
    function AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray): PointerToDatasetInfo ;
  end

function TDatasetInfo.AddChild(Dataset: TKpQuery; RelationFields: TStringDynArray: PointerToDatasetInfo ;
begin
  ...
  ...
  Result := @Self.Childs[Self.ChildCount - 1];
end;
```

If I add an indirection to the end of the AddChild call then I can change directly its content without needing to assign it first to a record variable.

```
with ADatasetInfo.AddChild(qProductRelatedStock, ['product'])^ do
  CascadeDeletes := False;
```

It's a bit annoying of having to add that indirection (`^`) at the end of the function call, but other than that it gives me the flexibility that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Records are not referenced types but instead managed types. What this means?

First thing you should know that each record actually represents one memory block with the size of a record. So when you assign record from one variable to second variable that variable won't point to the memory location at which the first record is stored but instead a new copy of the first record is made at the memory location to which the second variable points.

So when you assign a record to the result of a function you basically create a new copy of your record.

Check this short example:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    Num: Integer;
  end;

procedure TestRecordAssignment;
var Rec1,Rec2: TMyRec;
begin
  Rec1.Num := 1;
  Rec2 := Rec1;
  ShowMessage(Format('Record1.Num: %d Record2.Num: %d',[Rec1.Num,Rec2.Num]));
  Rec1.Num := 2;
  ShowMessage(Format('Record1.Num: %d Record2.Num: %d',[Rec1.Num,Rec2.Num]));
end;
```

You would expect that after the second change for `Rec1.Num` field is made that this change would also reflect in the `Rec2` but it does not since `Rec2` is a copy of `rec1` as it was at the time of the assignment.

And as with every function result Delphi then expects that you are going to assign result of this function to suitable variable or pass as parameter to another function/procedure. After such assignment is made the memory that was allocated for result is freed. So in a way if you would be assigning result of your function to some record variable that record variable would then actually contain the third copy of your original record.

---

So how to ensure that your function/procedure will be working on exactly same record that you then might be using further outside your function/procedure?

For this you need to create/declare your record outside your function/procedure and pass it to your function/procedure as [Variable Parameter](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters)

```
procedure MyProcedure(var MyRecord: TMyRecord);
```

Now whenever you are working with `MyRecord` within your procedure you are working with the same record that you have passed as parameter to the procedure.

Comment: "Records are not referenced types but instead managed types." Records are value types. Value types are being copied on assignment.

Comment: Thanks @SilverWarior, I have finally chosen to return a pointer of the internal record, so the calling procedure can change its content. I've seen that adding an indirection I can now use the `with` construction as I wanted :  with DsInfo.AddChildP^ do CascadeDeletes := False.